# What is "PrintStream target"?

Tags: java

```
public void print(PrintStream target) {
target.println(this.title);
target.println(this.firstName);
target.print(this.lastName);
}
```

Given this method, what should the main pass to the method as `target`? Also, what type of variable is `target`? What does it mean that it is of type `PrintStream?`

Comment: That is a function parameter of the type `PrintStream` that is named `target`. `PrintStream` is an object as you can read about [here in the docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html)

Comment: @SterlingArcher and what should the main pass to the method?

Comment: A `PrintStream`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`PrintStream` is a Java Object Type used to specify an output stream to which data can be written. In this case, you would probably pass the method the `System.out` print stream, as this will cause it to print to the main system console. This is the same `PrintStream` that you would write to when you call `System.out.println()`. In some cases, a different `PrintStream` could be used if the output was to go to a file or be uploaded to the web or similar purposes other than simply printing to the console.